# Finding Countif Excluding some columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

my data ...

```
====================================================================
+   A  +  B  +  C  +  D  +  E  +  F  +  G  +  H  +  I  +  J  +  K  + L
====================================================================
+  10  +  3  +  5  +  0  +  0  +  0  +  7  +  8  +  9  +  10 + 50 + 20
====================================================================
```

i want to use **CountIf** function in  A, D, G, J columns only. i wrote following formula.

```
=COUNTIF(A9:V9, ">0")/3
```

is there any alternate method ?  plz...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=INDEX(FREQUENCY((A9,D9,G9,J9),0),2)`

Comment: Jos Woolley @ tqs for you help... We r mentioning particularly A9, D9, G9, J9, is there any possibilities to tell COUNT 'A' column then skip two columns then count next column (Column D) and so on... tq u...

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
=SUM((A9:L9>0)*(MOD(COLUMN(A9:L9),3)=1))
```

Swap `SUM()` with `SUMPRODUCT()` for Excel versions prior to ms365

---

Or, if available:

```
=SUM(--TAKE(WRAPROWS(A9:L9,3)>0,,1))
```

Or:

```
=SUM(--TAKE(WRAPCOLS(A9:K9,3)>0,1))
```

Comment: WRAPROWS! Can't wait to get hold of that one! Re your first formula, you should probably generalize it such that it will work if the range referenced begins in any column. Changing it to B9:M9, for example, causes your current set-up to fail.